# What is the explicit best known quantum algorithm for LWE?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms, complexity-theory, quantum-advantage

Consider the learning with errors(LWE) problem which is known to be hard for quantum computers.

---

Let $q \geq 2$ be a prime integer. Consider us being given (polynomially many samples of) either:

$$A, As + e~~~(\text{mod}~q),~~\text{or}$$
$$A, u~~~(\text{mod}~q),$$

where we have:
\begin{align}
    s &\in \mathbb{Z}_{q}^{m}, \\
    A &\in_{U} \mathbb{Z}_{q}^{n \times m}, \\
    u &\in_{U} \mathbb{Z}_{q}^{m},
\end{align}

$\in_U$ means "sampled uniformly randomly from the set." $e$ is sampled from the distribution:

\begin{equation}
    D_{\mathbb{Z}_q, B^{'}}(x) = \frac{e^{\frac{- \pi ||x||^{2}}{B^{'2}}}}{\sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{n}, ||x|| \leq B'} e^{\frac{- \pi ||x||^{2}}{B^{'2}}}},
\end{equation}
where
$$B' = \frac{q}{C_{T} \sqrt{mn \log q}},$$
$C_{T}$ is a fixed constant. $q$ is polynomial in $n$.

---

What is the explicit best-known quantum algorithm for LWE? I could not find a description of any such algorithm but I found a hypothesis that the best-known quantum algorithm runs in exponential time.

Comment: I might have this wrong but I think that many such lattice problems can be reduced to the dihedral hidden subgroup problem, of which the best known quantum algorithms are indeed exponential.